# Expanding / collapsing groups in Google sheets without affecting other users views

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone help? I have a huge sheet with lots of filters and groups.  Does anyone know if a way I can great views with certain groups expanded and others collasped that doesnt affect what other users view?  in other words I want to expand certain groups but if anyone else is in the sheet they may want them collapsed, if that makes sense!

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User thress times.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, almost all view options are shared in real time between all users, which means that you cannot use grouped or hidden rows or columns without having other simultaneous users experience the same changes.

The only exception is [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) that let you and other users decide which rows to show at a time independently of each other, all without disturbing each other. Filter views also let you sort data *in the view*, without changing the storage order of rows. Filter views are different from regular filters.

You can save filter views and give them descriptive names. For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Comment: Filter views doesnt seem to work - I collapse and expand groups when in a filter view and other see the groups closing?!

Comment: Clarified the answer. Changes in row and column groups are visible to all users. Filter views are the only view type that is "private" to you.